# AsciiDoc: how can I get the author's name in the output document?

Tags: markup, asciidoc, author

This is the beginning of an AsciiDoc document, where the author is specified:

```
= Writing Documentation using AsciiDoc
Tom White <twhite@mymail.com>
v2.0, 2020-11-06
:toc:
```

The author name is accepted by the AsciiDoc processor, i.e. no error is produced, but it is not shown in the output document.

How is it possible to make the author's name visible?

Comment: What kind of output are you generating? HTML? PDF? EPUB?

Comment: @eskwayrd, I am generating HTML and PDF, but AFAIK that should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the default Asciidoctor templates for HTML output, the author and their email address is included beneath the document heading.

If you are using a custom template, then the author and email address are available as attributes that you can use at any location within your document, `{author}` and `{email}` respectively.

For details, see: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#author-and-email